# How can I fix my KDE theme after upgrading to Kubuntu 13.04?

Tags: kubuntu, themes, 13.04, gui

A while back, I installed Kubuntu 12.10 and switched to the [FormaN theme](http://kde-look.org/content/show.php?content=141963). Today, I completed my upgrade to Raring (13.04) and rebooted. Now all of the graphical controls appear messed up:

[image]

I've just finished a complete run of:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

...so I'm pretty sure everything is up to date.

How do I go about fixing this?

---

**Edit:** the problem appears to be with the "air" desktop theme. Switching to another desktop theme seems to resolve the problem - except I prefer the "air" theme.

Answer (score 3):

I was able to fix this problem by reverting all desktop theme settings, installing the [kdeartwork-theme-window [image: Install kdeartwork-theme-window]](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/kdeartwork-theme-window) package, and logging in again.

Comment: **Note:** I have no idea if the `kdeartwork-theme-window` package had anything to do with resolving the problem. The package's description has me wondering. But I thought I'd mention it here since that's what I did.